# how to send smtp email from blackberry app

Tags: java, android, blackberry, smtp

Hi i want to send smtp email from my blackberry app using java and javax, i already send smtp email from my android app using javax mail like this code:

```
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   
    message.setDataHandler(handler);   
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);
```

Is there a similar code to use in blackberry app to send smtp email ?

Comment: and what if you just build your android app for blackberry os and run it?

Comment: it is possible for blackberry bold and curve ? i know it work for bb10 but i want to buil it for all kind of blackberry

Comment: try this code- http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/search/label/Email

Comment: i try it  but it gives exception: exceptionnet.rim.blackberry.api.mail_SendFailedException:MAIL_API: No RIM Service Record

Comment: i think i must specify the host for smtp , or what do you think @Signare

Comment: @Malo you testing on simulator or real device?

Comment: on a real device blackberry bold

Comment: do i need to configure the email account on my device?

Comment: @Malo  yes. you have to configure email account on device. then only it will work.

Comment: okay thank you can you put it as an answer ? and i will accept it:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this-

```
Store store = Session.getDefaultInstance().getStore();
Folder[] folder = store.list(Folder.SENT);
Folder sent = folder[0];
Message msg = new Message(sent);
Address receipent[] = new Address[1];
 try
  {
    receipent[0] = new Address(To_Address, name);
                         msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, receipent);
                         msg.setSubject("Test Mail");
                         msg.setContent("This mail is to remind you that programmatically we can send the mail");
                         msg.setPriority(Priority.HIGH);
                         Transport.send(msg);
                 }

   catch (Exception e)
        {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
```